# Cycle Index of Alternating/Symmetric Group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For a homework assignment, I have to write down the cycle indices of

i) $A_4$

ii) $S_5$

I know how to write a cycle index once I have the elements of the group of permutations...but there has got to be an easier way to do this. Does this question really require me to write out each element of $A_4$ and $S_5$? Or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: There are only 7 different kinds of element in $S_5$: $(), (xx), (xxx),(xxxx),(xxxxx),(xx)(xx),(xxx)(xx)$. It's not that hard to work out how many there are of each type. Do you need any more information than that, to calculate the cycle index?

Comment: If you just want to look it up, the cycle index for the alternating and symmetric group is given at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index (scroll down towards the bottom).

Comment: There are some generating functions for famous groups, alternating and symmetric being among them. However it would likely take longer to use those generating functions than enumerating each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to write out each element, but you do have to know what kinds of element are there, and how many of each kind. I'll go through $A_4$ for you:

There's the identity element, which contributes $a_1^3$ to the cycle index.

There are three elements of the type $(xx)(xx)$, each of which contributes $a_2^2$.

And there are 8 elements of type $(xxx)$, each of which yields $a_1a_3$.